# Equivalent of volumes_from in Docker Compose v3

Tags: docker, docker-compose

There are seemingly similar questions here ([docker-compose volumes_from equivalent with version 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42232051/docker-compose-volumes-from-equivalent-with-version-3), [How to replace volumes_from in docker-composer v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42244079/how-to-replace-volumes-from-in-docker-composer-v3)) but I don't think they answer the question (or at least I don't understand how the answers solve the problem). So let me try to ask again, very specifically.

I have this v2 docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'
services:
  full-tests:
    volumes:
      - ..:/opt/project
      - ../../../ext-libs:/opt/ext-libs
      - ./third-mapping:/opt/third

  unit-tests:
    volumes_from: full-tests
```

The point is that the set of volumes is defined once and I can easily reuse them using `volumes_from`.

How would you rewrite this in v3?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To answer your question - its impossible with v3 - see the section below. v3 shall not be used as a successor ( also a official statement by docker ) it shall be used in "swarm cases".

nevertheless, what you do should do is using named volumes.

You can combine it with host-mount volumes like this

```
docker volume create --name volume1 -o type=none -o device=/home/$USER/projects/01 -o o=bind
```

You can simplify this using the long-syntax introduced in 3.2: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#long-syntax-2 so you can define the named volume + bind on the host in the docker-compose file
example:

```
services:
   full-tests:
    volumes:     
      - type: volume
        source: ../
        target: /opt/project
      - type: volume
        source: ../../../ext-libs
        target: /opt/ext-libs
```

or in short as you had

```
services:
   full-tests:
     volumes:     
      - ../:/opt/project
      - ../../../ext-libs:/opt/ext-libs
```

What you cannot do though, putting the long-syntax under the top-level "volumes" definition to give that volume a name and reused it in the volumes section in the services - that is not possible. To do so, you would use a

```
volumes:
  project:
    external: true
  third-party:
    external: true
```

And then use the "docker volume create" syntax on the cli to create those volumes with a bind option, as outlines above

but you will never get what volumes_from was doing for you here

---

There is no equivalent of volumes_from in v3, since v3 is not a successor of v2, its an alternative - please see my comment and the sources here https://github.com/rancher/rancher/issues/3316#issuecomment-310889283

To sum it up - volumes_from and volumes have an overlap in the case volumes_from was just used the wrong way / in the wrong field.

a) If you want data to be persisted *across* stack upgrades ( down + up ), you pick named volumes - and now, if 2+ services needs to share this, just mount this named volume using `volumes:`.

b) If you though, do *not* want the data to persist over stack upgrades ( e.g. because its source code and the image actually includes an upgrades this ) as a in a usual application + httpd/proxy scenario, you will create a anon-volume for this e.g. `/var/www` in the Dockerfile using `Volume /var/www` and then use volumes_from to mount it in the `httpd` service.

---

the main point with b is, that on stack upgrades, the anon volume will be removed ( `docker-compose down removes anon containers, but not named ones ) and thus the upgrade works as expected, you have a new codebase

Trying to do the same with named volumes will give you a huge suprise on the first upgrade, since the code is on a named volume and that will *overlay* the codebase on the "fresh" image / new container, thus you will run on the old codebase after the upgrade.

Comment: Thanks, best answer so far. So with the long syntax, I guess it's quite possible to get close to my v2 example with name volumes with `device` mapping? There would still be duplication between my two services but maybe there's a reason why v3 forces this duplication on me, I'm not sure.

Comment: yes, no way to go around that limitation, also see my comment here https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4693#issuecomment-310892561 ... but i consider your usecase to be one of the abuses they wanted to be stoped ( and i find it right to do so ) - no harsh feelings. And yes there is a reason when you think about spreading stuff across a swarm, host-mounts are more or less the blocker for that - its only available on one host, not all :)

Comment: Sure, my use case is a dockerized development environment, not a scalable runtime. So I'll have many similar "services" (one-time runners of tests in practice) and to each of those, I need to map a couple of local folders. (Host mapping is important for debugging.) Probably not the primary use case for docker-compose but v2 supported this nicely. I'll stick with that version then, hope it's not deprecated or something if it's just different (v3 not being a successor but an alternative).

Comment: Please accept the answer if you think it does answer your question. If you do run dev env you can try http://docker-sync.io ( i am biased ) which will partially solve your duplication issue ( you do not need to redefine the source and dest path )

Comment: Could you add a docker-compose v3 example with the `device` mapping? I don't see it documented in the official documentation and it would be best to see a concrete example as an answer to the question.

Comment: it is right here, with an example https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#userns_mode

Comment: I added some examples on also made the answer more complete according that its not possible for the top-level volume section and how to work around this

Answer (score 4):

You could use [extension fields](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#extension-fields) to keep the code short but it isn't quite the same as `volumes_from`. For example:

```yaml
version: '3.7'
x-volumes:
  &my-volumes
      - ..:/opt/project
      - ../../../ext-libs:/opt/ext-libs
      - ./third-mapping:/opt/third

services:
  full-tests:
    volumes:
      *my-volumes

  unit-tests:
    volumes:
      *my-volumes
```

Answer (score -1):

I got docker-compose version 3 working with unison. Basically had to replace "volumes_from" and create a global "volumes" declaration.

```
version: "3"
services:
  unison:
    container_name: xxx_unison
    image: onnimonni/unison
    environment:
      - UNISON_DIR=/var/www/$DOCKER_WEB_DOMAIN/htdocs/
      - UNISON_USER=www-data
      - UNISON_UID=1000
      - UNISON_GID=1001    
    volumes:
      - unison_file:/var/www/$DOCKER_WEB_DOMAIN/htdocs/
    networks: 
      - frontend    
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"    
  database: 
    container_name: xxx_database
    image: percona
    depends_on:
      - unison
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=xxx
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=xxx # Assign a database to be created on container first load  
    volumes: 
      - ./mysql/import:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      - ./mysql/data/:/var/lib/mysql/ 
      - ./logs:/var/log/mysql
      - ./mysql/conf:/etc/mysql/conf.d          
    ports: 
      - "3306:3306"
    networks: 
      - frontend
  web:
    container_name: xxx_web
    image: ubuntu
    depends_on:
      - unison    
    volumes: 
      - ./nginx/ssl/:/etc/nginx/ssl/ 
      - ./logs/:/var/log/nginx
      - ./shell/run.sh:/run.sh
      - unison_file:/var/www/$DOCKER_WEB_DOMAIN/htdocs/
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    networks: 
      - frontend
    env_file:
      - ./.env      
networks:
  frontend:
volumes:
  unison_file:
```